# How to use something like a logout required in django views?

Tags: python, django

I have a login and sign_up view like this:

```
def sign_up(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    registered = False 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            registered = True 
    
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'registered':registered,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/sign_up.html',context)

def login_page(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

    context = {
        'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/login.html',context)
```

What I actually want is that if the user is not logged out first and tries to access the sign up or login page, they are redirected to the logout page to first logout. So, they can't access these 2 pages unless they are logged out. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether a user is logged in or not;

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

if user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(reverse('logout_page_of_your_choice_where_you_want_to_redirect_the_user_if_he_is_logged_in'))
```

Use this code block in your above views(signup_page and login_page functions).

Comment: Yes, it worked. Stack overflow was showing me that I can mark this as accepted in 10 minutes. So i was waiting

Comment: Thanks! For your kind information, as it seems you are a beginner in the django, i will recommend ALLAUTH instead of AUTH for authentication in django as that gives a lot more features. You can use social account there to login, email authentication etc.